# There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified in the request

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files, blobstorage

I am using python sdk for this and want to perform move to blob from one container to another but lease creating problem after breaking the lease also.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobLeaseClient, BlobServiceClient
    from app.models.remediation import RemediationRequest, RemediationType
    from app.shared.azure_storage_client import AzureStorageClient

    def remediate(self, remediation_request: RemediationRequest, account: dict, 
    file_object_metadata: dict,destination_bucket_name: str):
        file_type = file_object_metadata["file_type"]
        storage_client = AzureStorageClient(account_name=key, account_key=Value)
        if file_object_metadata['lease']['status'] == 'locked':
            connection_string = storage_client._get_connection_string()

            blob_service_client = 
                BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

            container_client = 
                blob_service_client.get_container_client(source_bucket)

            blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)

            break_lease_result = BlobLeaseClient(blob_client).break_lease()

            storage_client.move_blob(blob_name, source_bucket, 
                 destination_bucket_name, destination_blob_name,file_type)
            
'''

blob should move with specify lease id else break the lease and move.
```

Answer (score 2):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

In my environment I have an two containers with name

1. Test
2. Test1

**Portal:**
[image]

In test container,I have a blob with leased state and also normal state.

**Portal(test container):**

[image]

After I tried with below code and the file is broken with lease and successfully copied from one container to another container.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobLeaseClient, BlobServiceClient

connect_strng="<connect string>"
source_blob="https://<storage acc name>.blob.core.windows.net/test/file.json"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_strng)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client("test", "file.json")
BlobLeaseClient(blob_client).break_lease()
copied_blob = blob_service_client.get_blob_client("test1", 'file.json')
copy = copied_blob.start_copy_from_url(source_blob)
props = copied_blob.get_blob_properties()
print(props.copy.status)
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[azure.storage.blob.BlobLeaseClient class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.BlobLeaseClient?view=azure-python)